# Хлебные крошки битрикс выводят неправильные ссылки

Tags: php, битрикс, breadcrumbs

У меня есть структура инфоблоков, выглядит вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идеи если я нахожусь на сайте в разделе `Линии` , то навигационная цепочка должна выглядить вот так

```
Категории / Красота / Линии
```

Если например в разделе `Здоровье` , то вот так

```
Категории / Здоровье
```

Но  у меня на всех сраницах выводится вот такое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть берутся все инфоблоки вообще , все возможные пути , и выводятся на экран. Как будто я одновременно нахожусь на 4-х страницах.
Почему так происходит? И как это исправить?

Вызов компонента

```
  <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:breadcrumb",
            "breadcrumb2019",
            array(
                "START_FROM" => "0",
                "PATH" => "",
                "SITE_ID" => "-",
                "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "breadcrumb2019"
            ),
            false
        );?>
```

Шаблон

```
<?php
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

/**
 * @global CMain $APPLICATION
 */

global $APPLICATION;
//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($arResult);
//exit();
//delayed function must return a string
if(empty($arResult))
    return "";

$strReturn = '';

//we can't use $APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS() here because we are inside the buffered function GetNavChain()
$css = $APPLICATION->GetCSSArray();

if(!is_array($css) || !in_array("/bitrix/css/main/font-awesome.css", $css))
{
    $strReturn .= '<link href="'.CUtil::GetAdditionalFileURL("/bitrix/css/main/font-awesome.css").'" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n";
}


$strReturn .= '<nav class="breadcrumbs">';

$itemSize = count($arResult);
for($index = 0; $index < $itemSize; $index++)
{
    $title = htmlspecialcharsex($arResult[$index]["TITLE"]);
    $arrow = ($index > 0? '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>' : '');

    if($arResult[$index]["LINK"] <> "" && $index != $itemSize-1)
    {
        $strReturn .= '

                <a href="'.$arResult[$index]["LINK"].'" title="'.$title.'" itemprop="url">'.
                    $title.
                '</a>';

    }
    else
    {
        $strReturn .= '

                <span itemprop="name">'.$title.'</span>';

    }
}

$strReturn .= '</nav>';

return $strReturn;
```

Comment: Какой шаблон для хлебных крошек используете? Какие настройки у компонентов каталога и хлебных крошек?

Comment: @NikolajSarry добавил в ответ